# Firmware update for ManagedGateway on Python

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-iot

In the Python GitHub documentation i see reference to [ManagedGateway](https://github.com/ibm-watson-iot/iot-python/blob/master/docs/GatewayManagement.rst), however, unlike the [Java documentation on Watson IOT site](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/gateways/libraries/java_cli_managed_gw.html#java_cli_managed_gw), the Python docs doesn't have any reference for firmware update.

Does the Python package supports Firmware update for Gateways?, or all must be done through the Notification function or by using a ManagedDevice ?

Answer (score 0):

@Yarh We are working on this functionality. However, check the 

`ibmiotf.gateway.ManagedClient` class, that provides ManagedGateway functionality.
In case that one does not address your requirements, please elaborate the requirement.